# How to use AttachAsModified function in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6.1

I'm having an issue with the `AttachAsModified` function in a newly created `.edmx` in EF6 - I don't see this function.

Earlier I was able to use this in EF 4 `withnamespace[System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll]`

e.g.

```
public virtual void Update(T entity, T original)
{
  if (original == null)
  {
    this.ObjectSet.AttachAsModified(entity);
  }
  else
  {
    this.ObjectSet.AttachAsModified(entity, original);
  }
}
```

Comment: `AttachAsModified` is a method on the `ObjectContext` class - EF6 by default creates a `DbContext` instead - which doesn't have this function

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you ? As explained here [Entity Framework Add/Attach & Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx)

```
var existingBlog = new Blog { BlogId = 1, Name = "ADO.NET Blog" }; 

using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
{ 
    context.Entry(existingBlog).State = EntityState.Modified; 

    // Do some more work...  

    context.SaveChanges(); 
}
```